# EF scaffold, resolve ambiguous types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are currently moving from Linq2Db to EF. Because we use the Database First Approach, I'm currently creating a tool to create all the models and contexts from multiple databases. This is the command executed:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(
    "/C dotnet-ef dbcontext scaffold \"{0}\" \"{1}\" -o \"{2}\" --context-dir \"{3}\" -n \"{4}\" --context-namespace \"{5}\" -c \"{6}\" --no-onconfiguring"
    database.Connection, database.Provider,
    Path.Join(database.ModelsOutputDir, modelSubNameSpace), database.ContextOutputDir,
    $"{database.ModelsNameSpace}.{modelSubNameSpace}", database.ContextNameSpace,
    database.ContextName
);
```

The problem is that in one of the databases there is a table called *EventHandler*. So the created model is called `EventHandler`, which conflicts with the `System.EventHandler`. So every following build fails.

So how can I specify, that EF scaffold should specify the model namespace if there are ambiguous type definitions?

P.S.: I cannot rename the table to resolve the problem because the table is created by an external service

Comment: You solve this the same way you solve any naming conflict: you either only import one namespace, you rename the conflicting class, or you fully specify its name when you use the class (or when you alias it). Renaming the conflicting class is trivial; you can tell EF that the EventHandlerXXX entity is backed by the EventHandler table even just using a `[Table(` attribute on the entity

Comment: Yes like I said, I want EF scaffold to automatically fully specify the Name e.g. `Model.Namespace.EventHandler`. I cannot do it afterward because all builds after this database fail. So I would have to restart the tool which overrides everything. Also, I could move this database to the end so there is no build after this, but if I have 2 databases with the same problem then this does not work

Comment: are you doing a re-scaff every time you change the DB (e.g. as opposed to migrations) ? Just wondering if youre looking for a one time fix or a many time fix. I suspect that EF Core Power Tools can rename entities.. https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/issues/188 - so you can tell EFCPT when it does a reverse, to rename EventHander to something else that doesn't conflict

Comment: I'm looking for a many-time fix because every time I execute this tool everything is deleted to prevent artifacts. So all builds have to succeed, so the namespace of the model has to be added to the name

Comment: You're going to re-scaff the DB on every *build*, wow.. OK, I'd say to take a look at EFCPT to rename the entity as part of the scaffing it does. I fully expect that EFCPT can be wired into a pre-build - I;ve never looked at doing it but I'm aware that the VS extension essentially just writes a config file then calls an exe to do the work, so calling the same exe directly should be possible. See if there's something in the wiki, or the author @ErikEJ posts here so maybe he will offer some tips

Comment: No, I don't re-scaff on every build. It's an external tool that deletes all models and contexts in the destination project and inserts the new ones. And every database scaffold job builds the destination project. That's what I mean with build

Comment: I see. My recommendation remains the same; take a look at EFCPT, configure it to rename the EventHandler entity and then look at wiring it into the build process

Comment: Okay EFCPT is a nice tool. Unfortunately, the database that causes the problems is a Firebird DB and it seems like I cannot add this provider to the tools, so I cannot even test if renaming works.

Comment: If you click the down arrow next to Add, and Add Custom Connection - i see firebird in there.. Does it not work out? (I've never used it) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuzV3.png

Comment: @CaiusJard Okay, I tried it now and it does not work. I cannot rename the created Entity `EventHandler` but only its Properties so columns or the name of the `DbSet`-property, so the table name

Comment: Have you got a full code to reproduce the problem? I can install PG and try to rep ro its